# Splitting a question

Tags: discussion

Can a mod split this [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3022/903) into 2 questions, and move the corresponding answers?

Comment: We can't split questions, no.

Comment: @Undo Thanks. What's the best option then?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure myself - let's let the community figure that out ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a mod, but I took the initiative and split the 2 questions.

I also left a comment to the single answer that was about the second question, asking to move and promising to upvote.

Please everyone upvote [Craig's moved answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3726/140) so that he does not lose in the process.

Learnt lesson: split such cases as early as possible, if possible before answers appear.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted!